# Applying a custom filter to everything behind a RECT with C++, a'la CSS backdrop-filter style

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, winapi, gdi+

I want to invert the colors of everything in a window from, say, `(300, 100)` to `(600, 500)`.

I tried using `BitBlt` with the `DSTINVERT` flag set from the `winuser.h` library, but if anything changes, it breaks. Having it continuously invert in a loop also doesn't work, as it will invert already inverted parts.

I also tried `RedrawWindow` in combination with `BitBlt` in a loop in order to redraw the parts I would need to invert, and while it does successfully redraw the window and invert it, it results in some pretty bad flickering.

My current code:

```
RedrawWindow(hwnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_UPDATENOW | RDW_INVALIDATE);

BitBlt(
        GetDC(hwnd),
        300, 100,
        600, 500,
        NULL,
        0, 0,
        DSTINVERT
);
```

Example of what I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: To avoid flickering I suggest you could try to use double buffering method.In this method we do painting procedure over off screen DC (hdcBuffer) and then copy the content of that DC to actual screen DC (hdc).

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT The flickering is occurring because we need to wait before the window itself updates (returns to its original color), and then we process and apply it (returns to its modified color). In my case, the original color is white and the processed color is black, resulting in flicker, so I'm afraid I can't really utilize double buffering here.

Here's a diagram to show what's happening: https://i.imgur.com/e9vdZaq.png